# Arithmetic overflow error saving small enough number with linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, bigint

When I try to save the number `5906560069339` using linq in a `bigint` sql column (`Int64` linq) I get the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. The statement has been terminated.

Specifically:

```
var p = db.Table.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
p.Phone = 5906560069339;
db.SaveChanges();
```

The table `Table` has the column `Phone` as a bigint and everything is up to date. As I've read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) this number is not that big so it shouldn't be a problem. What's wrong?

Edit: I *know* it's better to treat regular phones as strings (`varchar`) but I'm not working with common phone numbers (as you can see with the number) and either way I'd like to know *why* is this not working.

Comment: BigInt on SQL, it says Int64 on linq

Comment: I assume you took Phone as int type property in Table class.

Comment: Typically phone numbers should be stored as strings.

Comment: Storing phone numbers in a numeric field is a really really bad idea. In Europe, area codes commonly start with zero. With numeric fields, you just lost that (very important) leading zero. International codes commonly start `+` to indicate the international prefix... where did that go?

Comment: It's not for a common phone number (as you can see); they are a special long only-number kind. And treating them as number is better in perforamnce that in varchar (I checked)

Comment: It looks like your entity model has a property `Phone` that is an `int` not a `long`, even though it is mapped to a `bigint` column on the DB. Show us the C# definition of the `Phone` property.

Comment: Do you have any computed columns or triggers on the DB that might be doing calculations that overflow?

Comment: @petelids precisely a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

Everything I said is correct:

- Have a `Bigint` on the SQL column.
- Be sure to have a `Int64` - `Long` on the schema
- Be sure to have the schema updated!

But I failed to account for the Triggers the table might have. Some ***super nice*** developer decided that whenever an update was being made to the table ***ANOTHER*** table with ***THE SAME*** columns whould be used as an intermediary. I deleted the trigger (since it was *stupid*) and it worked.

So the conclusion is:

- CHECK for triggers that might be thrown.
- DON'T work with *stupid* developers.

Comment: IMO triggers == bad, every time.